# Grails GORM getting people with both tags

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have the classes:

```
class Person {
    static hasMany = [tags: Tag]
}

class Tag {
}
```

To get the people that have at least one of the tags from tagList I could create a criteria

```
public Criteria hasAtLeastOneOf(List<Tag> tagList) {
    return Person.createCriteria().buildCriteria {
        'tags' {
          'in' 'id', tagList.collect{it.id}
        }
    }
}
```

What kind of criteria do I need to create to get all the people that have each one of the tags from tagList (eg. tagList[0] and tagList[1], etc.)

Comment: What is wrong with this `criteria` ?

Comment: The criteria returns the people that have tagList[0] or tagList[1].
I want to have the people which have tagList[0] and tagList[1].

Comment: Can you post the SQL logs generated for this criteria execution?

Comment: please join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159807/grails

Comment: can you give an SQL that matches to your idea?

Comment: For 2 tags the SQL will be like

      select
        distinct v1.PERSON_TAGS_ID
        from PERSON_TAG v1
      inner join PERSON_TAG v2
        on v1.PERSON_TAGS_ID = v2.PERSON_TAGS_ID
      where
        v1.TAG_ID = [tag1]
        and v2.TAG_ID= [tag2];

Comment: so, for 3 tags, you will need 3 joins? does your sql gives user with 2 given tags?

Comment: Yes, for 3 tags the 3 joins would be needed. And yes, the SQL gives person ids with 2 given tags.

Comment: i think, it will be better if you do -> find user where user_tag_count == total_tag_count [pseudo] what do you say?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160008/discussion-between-devbd-and-greg-zuber).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this unanswered question:

[Grails 2.5.1 (hibernate 3) criteria multiple joins to same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453576/grails-2-5-1-hibernate-3-criteria-multiple-joins-to-same-table)

In short you need multiple joins between Person and Tag, one for each tag in the list that you want to compare.  As the comments on the linked issue describe, this can be done in HQL by building the joins manually, but criteria doesn't (seem to?) support this.